# When I try to update/set a datetime I get an invalid mysql syntax 1064

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, query

I copy a value from the pre-existing values.

I update the date.  I do an update query.

It has an issue and the issue seems to be the time.

Here's my query:

```
UPDATE xxxxx_eb_events 
Set event_date 019-04-01 00:00:00;
```

**event_date** is of type datetime

And the error

```
    Error
    Static analysis:

    2 errors were found during analysis.

    Unexpected character. (near ":" at position 52)
    Unexpected character. (near ":" at position 55)
    SQL query:

        UPDATE gsti1_eb_events Set event_date 019-04-01 00:00:00

        MySQL said: Documentation

        #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '019-04-01 00:00:00' at line 2
```

It's complaining about the colons in the time but I copied and pasted them from the already existing entry.

I know 019 looks like a strange year, I have tried it with

```
UPDATE gsti1_eb_events 
Set event_date 19-04-01 00:00:00;
```

And I have tried

```
UPDATE gsti1_eb_events 
Set event_date 2019-04-01 00:00:00;
```

And I have tried enclosing all of them in single quotes

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: I think this is my table schema `Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)` and my MySQL version `Server version: 5.6.40-84.0-log - Percona Server (GPL), Release 84.0, Revision 47234b3` I got this from PHP MyAdmin, if it's wrong is there a better place to find it?

Comment: Forgive me being so noob.  I went to the table structure and `type` is `datetime`.  Is that the information you're asking me for?

Comment: You sure there isn't any hidden character? Position 52 & 55 are minutes and seconds.

Comment: That is right, they are, and nope, have retyped them to No avail

Comment: I think I Need to use backticks ``` and not single quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[9.1.3 Date and Time Literals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html)

**Enclosing that datetime string in single quotes**, `'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'` should work:

```
UPDATE xxxxx_eb_events 
Set event_date = '2019-04-01 00:00:00';
```

Comment: And that is a very strange year.

Comment: Updated answer.  I had tried that already.  Thanks for responding, not sure why everyone is so quick to jump on a new user like that. I appreciate your help.